# Are these examples of a dual space elements?

Tags: functional-analysis

I want to find three examples of elements of a dual space of $E$.

Let $$E=C[a,b]$$ with norm $||x||=\underset{a\le t\le b}{max}|x(t)|$.

*Definition: In mathematics, any vector space V has a corresponding dual vector space consisting of all linear forms on V, together with the vector space structure of pointwise addition and scalar multiplication by constants. *

Since the space is of continuous functions, I assume I have to take examples of continuous functions such as $\sin t$, $\sin t+\cos t$ , $C\cos t$ and not vectors. All reference to dual spaces online are related to vectors. But this question is related to functions.

How do I find examples of continuous functions for a definition made on vectors, under the given circumstances? Would it be better to use a truncated Power series of the trigonometric forms above? Or are these not right examples?

Update:

Let $\sin t$, $\cos t$ and $C\cos t$ be elements of $E$. Then an element of $E^*$ is

$$\bullet  (f+λg)(a)=f(a)+λg(a)$$

This would give $\sin(a)+\lambda\sin(a) \in E^*$

Any ideas what is missing?
Thanks

Comment: Basically, functions *are* vectors. Sure, often the word "vectors" is implied to mean elements of $\mathbb{R}^n$ or $\mathbb{C}^n$, but the definition of vector space is way more general and encompasses sequences, functions, functions of sequences, sequences of functions, functions of functions, and so on... Any additive group with a scalar multiplication based on a field is a vector space, by definition.

Comment: As for elements of the dual space of $E$, you need to think about linear applications from $E$ to $\mathbb{R}$. I'll give you one to start: $f \mapsto f(a)$ is in the dual space of $E$. Since a norm has been provided however, I'm guessing that you need the topological dual (algebraic dual is all linear forms, while topological dual is all *continuous* linear forms; there is no difference in finite dimension but there is in infinite-dimensional spaces like $E$ is), so you'll want to find functionals and check if they're bounded (= continuous) I'm assuming.

Comment: I think you're a bit confused: yes $\sin$, $\cos$ are elements of $E$ (just like $x \mapsto 0$, $x \mapsto x^2$, $\exp$, and so on), but elements of the dual will be linear functionals that take functions as input and give a real as an output. For example, I said $f \in E \mapsto f(a)$. It's linear because $(f+\lambda g)(a) = f(a) + \lambda g(a)$. That is different from $f \mapsto \sin a$ like you proposed which is not linear.

Comment: I think the root of your problems is your "definition" of the dual space. It is incorrect. "The sum of all linear forms of any vector" makes no sense. So maybe check that in your notes.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Fortunately, that definition is from Wikipedia: "In mathematics, any vector space V has a corresponding dual vector space consisting of all linear forms on V, together with the vector space structure of pointwise addition and scalar multiplication by constants" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_space

Comment: The definition in Wikipedia is perfect: your version is nonsense. Seriously, the fact that you re-write it in a meaningless way suggests that you don't understand it, and that's what you should be concentrating on first.

Comment: You have now pasted in the Wikipedia definition. If you look at it you will see that is says something quite different from your "definition". Shouting at someone trying to help you  get this sorted doesn't help.

Comment: Sorry, you are right.